# How can I compare 2 Array in Expression board Analysis in foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I try to deal with a variable which is a array (because allowed multiple values).

How can I compare each value of the variable to a string or to another array?

Answer (score 1):

Done, to resolve my problem I had use `"LIKE"` as it:

```
CAST ($Parameter AS STRING) LIKE '%'||"stringToCheck"||'%'
```